# I want to make a button that inputs an answer to a question when clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry if this is very basic but I'm very new to programming, I want to make a button that, when clicked, inputs an answer just like a person would write it on their keyboard and press 'enter', so for example, a button that says "Spain", and when clicked will input "France" to the question: flag=input("What flag do you want? "), Just like a person may write "France" after the question.

I've seen that the 'Entry' widget exists, but that doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for, as someone still has to manually write the answer into a box

```
flag=input("What flag do you want? ")
flag = flag.upper()
```

A button with a title that, when presses, will input that title (I don't know how to describe where it inputs it, but I want the same result as when someone writes the answer after the question and the code saves it as (flag)

Comment: The entry widget is an object, and that object has methods you can use to insert and delete characters. I recommend you reading the documentation on the entry widget, and playing around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'command' option of the tkinter button to call a function when it is clicked.

Here is a very simple question-answer app that you can use for reference.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
def wrong():
    messagebox.showinfo("","Wrong")
def correct():
    messagebox.showinfo("","Correct")

l = Label(root, text="What is 2+2? ")
b1 = Button(root, text="Four", command=correct)
b2 = Button(root, text="Three", command=wrong)
b3 = Button(root, text="Two", command=wrong)
b4 = Button(root, text="One", command=wrong)
l.grid(row=0, column=0)
b1.grid(row=0, column=2)
b2.grid(row=0, column=3)
b3.grid(row=1, column=3)
b4.grid(row=1, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example using `insert`:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

T = Entry(window)
T.pack()

def clicked():
    T.insert(0, "some text")

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=clicked)

btn.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't know if this is 100% what I'm looking for, it is a button that inserts a text which is partly what I want, but I would like to know how I could, or if I could at all, use this text itself as an input to the question in some way. Essentially, I would want my section of the code: (elif flag == "FRANCE":) to be triggered when the "France" button is pressed.